# Environment properties of Spring Boot OCI image aren't picked up by CNB launcher

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle-kotlin-dsl, buildpack

I'm building a Spring Boot 3.1.0 application and deploying it by means of Cloud Native Buildpacks from a Gradle Kotlin DSL build script. To tune some image properties, I'm setting the following in my `build.gradle.kts` script:

```kotlin
tasks.named<BootBuildImage>("bootBuildImage") {
    verboseLogging.set(true)
    // ...
    environment.set(mapOf(
        "BPL_JMX_ENABLED" to "true",        
        "BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED" to "true",  
        "BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED" to "false",
        "BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED" to "true"
    ))
}
```

I even see in the build log that these properties are recognized during build stage:

```
...
[creator]    Launch Configuration:           
[creator]      $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED       true         enables Java remote debugging support
[creator]      $BPL_DEBUG_PORT          8000         configure the remote debugging port
...
[creator]    Launch Configuration:
[creator]      $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED  true   whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
...
```

However, when the app is starting as a Docker container, none of the properties are picked up by the launcher. Here is an excerpt from the container's stdout with manual line breaks for clarity:

```
Spring Cloud Bindings Enabled
2023-05-20T07:48:25.857843881Z Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
-Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties 
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=1 
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M 
-Xmx31494K 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=97109K 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M 
-Xss1M 
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary 
-XX:+PrintNMTStatistics 
-Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
2023-05-20T07:48:28.285693854Z
```

I expect here to see "*Spring Cloud Bindings **Disabled***" and a JVM option like `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000`. Accordingly, none of the desired ports opened.

No errors or warnings were observed neither in the build log nor in the run log.

How can I understand what went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [two types of environment variable configuration properties that Paketo buildpacks understand](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#environment-variables): build time and launch time (also called run time).

- Build time environment configuration settings all start with `BP_`.
- Launch time environment configuration settings all start with `BPL_`.

You can set build time properties as environment variables passed to pack (`pack build -e ..`) or to Spring Boot build tools as you're doing here.

To set launch time configuration, you need to set those environment variables using your container runtime of choice. That could be Docker or Kubernetes or CloudFoundry or whatever.

In this case, you're using `docker run`, so you'd add `-e BPL_JMX_ENABLED=true -e BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED=true -e BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED=true -e BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED=true`.

The reason there is a difference is so that you can toggle these settings on/off **without** rebuilding your container.

If you would like to have these settings baked into the container image so they are automatic, you can do that. The [process is defined here](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#image-embedded-environment-variables).

In short, you'd modify your configuration like this:

```
    environment.set(mapOf(
        "BPE_DEFAULT_BPL_JMX_ENABLED" to "true",        
        "BPE_DEFAULT_BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED" to "true",  
        "BPE_DEFAULT_BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED" to "false",
        "BPE_DEFAULT_BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED" to "true"
    ))
```

Then when you build, these environment variables will be activated automatically. You won't need to include them with your runtime configuration.

The downside as I mentioned above is that you'll need to rebuild the image when you want to change them.

Comment: also, about `BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED` - at build time you can make sure the `spring-cloud-bindings` jar is not added using `BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED=true`

Comment: @daniel-mikusa, thanks for the detailed answer but it didn't help so far. The only change I see is that Spring Cloud Bindings are not enabled now (apparently due to `BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED=true`). But the JVM options stay the same. I've also tried to combine `BPL_` + `BPE_` options and the result hasn't changed. I've read the documentation you referenced, but still haven't understood why should I set `BPE_`-prefixed variables when the Bellsoft Liberica Buildpack expects `BPL_`-prefixed ones? (and yes, setting them via SB Gradle plugin is preferrable over container runtime)

Comment: `BPE_` environment variables are handled specially by the environment-variables buildpack. They get embedded into the image with the `BPE_` prefix stripped. Thus if you add `BPE_DEFAULT_BPL_JMX_ENABLED=true` then you should end up with an image that has `BPL_JMX_ENABLED=true` set as a default env variable in the resulting image. You can then run your image without specifying that variable at runtime because it is set within the image. I recommend default, because you can typically that's what you want when you embed an env var, you want a different default value.

Comment: That's it! I didn't fully realize that `BPE_` prefix should be used *alongside with* `BPL_` but not instead of it (though you've shown this in the answer). Now it has finally become clear. Thank you!